# Android studio doesn't recognize main file format

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I created new Flutter project, When it compiled, i noticed that all text is grey, and main file is formatted as text file. When i create other files in dart format it works properly, but when i try to create the main, it refactors it back to text.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the `Dart` and `Flutter` plugins?

if it's already installed, try this:

(override file type to `Dart`)

[image]

[image]